# How to find unique combination from join in sql server

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have two tables T1 and T2 as below,
I have two tables as below,

```html
ID D  V A
1 d1 v1 -70
2 d1 v2 70
3 d1 v3 -70
4 d2 v1 120

ID D  V A
1 d1 v11 -70
2 d1 v12 70
3 d1 v13 -70
4 d2 v31 -120
```

```html
ID D  V A
1 d1 v11 -70
2 d1 v12 70
3 d1 v13 -70
4 d2 v31 -120
```

I need to find out the unique combinations of records who's amounts results in zero. Following is the expected result set.

```html
D V
d1 v2
d1 v11
d1 v1
d1 v12
d2 v1
d2 v31
```

D   V
d1  v2
d1  v11
d1  v1
d1  v12
d2  v1
d2  v31

I have tried with inner join on column D and Amount using Row_Number() function but does not fully satisfy my requirement. It only gives first unique combination.

```
,temp1 as (select a.V as V1 ,b.V as V2,a.D as d1 ,b.D as d2,a.A as Actual ,b.A as Acrual  
           from T1 a  inner join T2 b on a.D =b.D 
           where a.Actual +b.Acrual = 0)

Select * 
from tbl a inner join 
         (select V1,V2,d1,d2, Actual,Acrual, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by v1 order by v1) as R1 ,Row_Number() over(partition by v2 order by v2) as R2 
          from temp1)f on (a.V = f.v1 or a.V = f.v2) and a.D = f.d1  
where R1 = 1 and R2 = 1
```

If I remove condition R1=1 and R2=1 condition and put R1=R2 the wrong combination also get selected ( v2- v13 this combination also get selected).

Comment: I don't understand the expected result set.  Can you explain that?  From what you describe, why isn't `T1.id = 1` and `T2.id = 2` in the result set?

Comment: Amount should result in zero. and if the one voucher from t1  is matching with different vouchers from T2 then result set should only have one combination. example v1 and v11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Answer:
I am slightly confused by your example result in the fiddle. You said you wanted unique pairs, so why does the below appear twice?:

```
insert into result (Dossier,voucher) values('d1','y100022')
insert into result (Dossier,voucher) values('d1','y100022')
```

Anyway assuming you want any given row in a table to be part of only 1 pair e.g.
Should be returned by query:
d1 x10002
d1 y100022
Should NOT be returned by the query:
d1 x10002
d1 y100033

use below query:

```
WITH UniquePairs( aID, bID, aR, bR )
AS
(
    SELECT a.ID, b.ID,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by a.Dossier, a.Voucher order by a.Dossier, a.Voucher) as aR,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by b.Dossier, b.Voucher order by b.Dossier, b.Voucher) as bR
    FROM T1 AS a
        INNER JOIN T2 AS b ON a.Dossier = b.Dossier AND a.amount+ b.amount = 0
)
SELECT a.Dossier, a.Voucher
FROM UniquePairs
    INNER JOIN T1 AS a ON aID = a.ID
WHERE aR = 1 AND bR = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT b.Dossier, b.Voucher
FROM UniquePairs
    INNER JOIN T2 AS b ON bID = b.ID
WHERE aR = 1 AND bR = 1
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanx for response!, I have created sample SQL fiddle. I have also created sample result set for your reference.  Your query gives result set as of mine.

Comment: Note: I added ID IDENTITY columns to your tables to make it easier to join

Comment: Hi alex, that raw was added two times mistakenly. and your query works perfectly. Thank you!n :)

Comment: You are welcome, please mark the answer as accepted if you are happy with it, or let me know if I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

The following query is a bit long winded but it should do the job.

```
    DECLARE @SetA TABLE     -- Create memory table for sample set A
    (
         ID INT NOT NULL
        ,D VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
        ,V VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
        ,A INT NOT NULL
    )

    DECLARE @SetB TABLE     -- Create memory table for sample set B
    (
         ID INT NOT NULL
        ,D VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
        ,V VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
        ,A INT NOT NULL
    )


    INSERT INTO @SetA   -- Create sample set A
    (
         ID
        ,D 
        ,V 
        ,A 
    )
    SELECT 1, 'd1', 'v1', -70 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'd1', 'v2', 70 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'd1', 'v3', -70 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'd2', 'v1', 120 


    INSERT INTO @SetB  -- Create sample set B
    (
         ID
        ,D 
        ,V 
        ,A 
    )
    SELECT 1, 'd1', 'v11', -70 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'd1', 'v12', 70 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'd1', 'v13', -70 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'd2', 'v31', -120 
    ;

    WITH CTE_Total  -- Join the two data sets and calculate the sum between all combinations.
    AS
    (
        SELECT      A.D
                    ,A.V  AS V_A
                    ,B.V AS V_B
                    ,(A.A + B.A) AS Total
                    ,(CAST(A.A AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + (CAST(B.A AS VARCHAR(10))) ) AS [Expression]
        FROM        @SetA A
        INNER JOIN  @SetB B ON A.D = B.D
    )
    ,
    CTE_ExpressionCounts -- Use ROW_NUMBER to determine number of occurrence of each A and B set combination for a specific expression.
    AS
    (
        SELECT   TOP 100 PERCENT 
                 D
                ,V_A
                ,V_B
                ,[Expression]
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Expression] ORDER BY V_B) AS RepeatCount
        FROM    CTE_Total
        WHERE   Total = 0 
        ORDER BY V_B, V_A
    )
    SELECT   D  
            ,V
            ,SortOrder
    FROM    (
                SELECT   D
                        ,V_A AS V
                        ,((ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY D, V_B) * 2) - 1)  AS SortOrder
                FROM    CTE_ExpressionCounts
                WHERE   RepeatCount = 1
            ) A -- Select set A
    UNION
    SELECT   D
            ,V
            ,SortOrder
    FROM    (
                SELECT   D
                        ,V_B AS V
                        ,((ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY D, V_B) * 2) )  AS SortOrder
                FROM    CTE_ExpressionCounts
                WHERE   RepeatCount = 1
            ) B -- Select set B
    ORDER BY SortOrder -- Note that the SortOrder column is not needed simply used to order result set.
```

Comment: Thanks Edmond, I have tried your sample queries but does not satisfy my requirement. Please see the SQL fiddle I have shared above. I have covered all possible combinations that should be present in final result set  there.

Comment: Seems I misunderstood the exact type of uniqueness you require on the possible combinations of the two sets.